# linking to method in rails via link_to function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, routes, haml, link-to

I recently added a new method (called "help") to my projects controller (projects_controller.rb), and created a "help.html.haml" in the views directory.

I added the following route in routes.rb:

```
 resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :help]
 resources :projects, :module => 'users' do
   get  :help, :on => :member, :as => :help
 end
```

***My goal is to create a link on a separate view (let's call it index.html.haml) that would link to help.html.haml.*** Note: at present my routes is set up to display help with the following URL: http://localhost:3001/projects/id/help

Unfortunately I don't know how to write the code to link to the help URL listed above. As of now I have the following code in index.html.haml:

```
 %li= link_to 'quick help', project_path(@project)
```

but this code only takes me to http://localhost:3001/projects/id. Is it possible to add the "/help" to the URL using the link_to function, or is there a better way to do this?

I sincerely appreciate any help. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the components of the route you've defined:

```
get :help, :on => :member, :as => :help
```

- The first parameter is `:help`, that's the name of the action that will be invoked.
- The second part is `:on => :member`, which means that the action is scoped on a specific record. So, you're going to have to pass an id to invoke it.
- The third part, `:as => :help`, defines the name of the helper method that you can use to generate the url. That's what you're looking for.

Basically, `help_project_path(@project)` will generate the url you need. So, the link would look like this:

```
%li= link_to 'quick help', help_project_path(@project)
```

Note that you don't really need the `:as => :help` path, it should be `help` by default. That's generally used if you want a different helper name.

Another thing I'd like to point out is that you're not creating "a link to help.html.haml", you're creating a link to the `help` action on the `projects` controller. The action can redirect somewhere if it's necessary, you don't have to render the view. I'm just saying this, because it sounds like you're still a bit new to this, sorry if I've simply misunderstood.

Comment: Andrew, thanks so much mate! I appreciate you taking the time to explain everything so clearly. That's something that I really enjoy as, you guessed it, I'm relatively new to ROR so the more detail and explanation that I get the better i'll be moving forward. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What does the **help** method do? Is it a help method for each project, or it is help for projects in general. You can create a route as follows:

```
match '/projects/help/:id' => 'projects#help', :via => :get
```

for :via, you choose a REST method i.e. either GET, POST, PUT, etc, as per your requirement.

If you are trying to create a help page for projects in general, this might not be useful. Whenever you have a URL as **/projects/<>**, Rails will try to route it to a project show page, and tries to use **<>** as ID of the project.

The link_to that you are using, with **project_path(@project)** will take you to the **project show** page for the object **@project**.

So, finally, this is what you should do. I would advise you to create a separate controller, which is used for general pages. Say, you have a controller **OtherController**

```
match '/help', :controller => 'other', :action => 'help', :via => :get
```

And then create a help.html.erb page for the view. Hope this works for you.